# Mapping Angular's Classes ng-valid .ng-invalid, .ng-pristine, etc. to bootstrap's is-invalid, .is-valid ./. :invalid, :valid and .was-validated

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an application utilizing Angular Bootstrap. Unfortunately, I got stuck at form validation. To the best of my (very limited) knowledge, Angular adds various classes to provide validation-feedback: `.ng-valid`, `.ng-invalid`, `.ng-pending`, `.ng-pristine`, `.ng-dirty`, `.ng-untouched` and `.ng-touched` (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes)

Bootstrap - however - relies on `:invalid` and `:valid` to a parent with class `.was-validated` for client-side and `.is-invalid`, `.is-valid` and `.invalid-feedback` for server-side validation. (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/)

Intuitively, I'd had expected that ng-bootstrap adds bootstrap's classes to DOM elements - effectively providing feedback according to Angular's form validation result. But apparently, this doesn't come by default so far.

Searching the web, I found various ideas for setting classes conditionally. Some use ternary operators (rather clumsy), others propose custom directives (more elegant). However, the more I try to write reusable and elegant code, the merrier it feels like framework-code that might exist in ng-bootstrap already.

Unfortunately, I've found anything specific: I.e. What is the canonical way for providing validation results when using ng-bootstrap? I'd be great if you could help me here, Thanks in advance, Frank

Comment: Perhaps you can create a directive with selector `input.ng-valid` which applies a `@HostBinding('class.is-valid') valid = true`